# I just bought ASUS UX434FLC-UH76T from Costco. This laptop is on BestBuy.com for $1199 but it's model number is UX434FLC-XH77. What's the difference?

Tags: asus-laptop

Costco sells an ASUS 14 inch laptop model UX434FLC-UH76T. BestBuy.com sells the same laptop but it's model number is UX434FLC-XH77. The last digits are different but what's the difference? I have tried to google this but can't find any information. They both have the same processor, memory, chassis, color, and screen size.

Comment: The UX434FLC-XH77 seems to be a newer model, or the other one may be vendor specific.

Comment: Stores routinely require a manufactured product to be its own SKU even if that SKU is identical to another SKU.  This prevents price matching.  You should compare the specifications of both models to determine their differences

Answer (score 2):

The XH77 has a 512GB SSD according to [the Asus Store](https://store.asus.com/us/item/201910AM040000003/A50187-ASUS-ZenBook-14-Ultra-Slim-Laptop-14%E2%80%9D-Full-HD-NanoEdge-Bezel%2C-Intel-Core-i7-10510U%2C-16GB-RAM%2C-512GB-PCIe-SSD%2C-GeForce-MX250%2C-Innovative-ScreenPad%E2%84%A2-2.0%2C-Windows-10-Pro%2C-UX434FLC-XH77%2C-Royal-Blue). Your UH76T has a 1GB SSD according to the Costco website.
That explains the price difference of $100.

Since your UH76T seems to be a Costco exclusive, there could however be subtler differences such as memory and/or ssd manufacturer. These would need you to run a hardware analysis tool on each one machine, or open them up to look inside.